# Merge coverage files with istanbul

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, istanbul

I have a situation where all my tests run in parallel and it creates the coverage report.

I was able to create a separate coverage folder for each test with the `--dir` option in the command line, which is great.

Now that I have all of these folders with coverage details, is it possible to merge all of these files into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered that `istanbul report` does the merging of the files by default, which is what I was after.

Answer (score 3):

Extending your finding a little bit, in favor of other lost souls like me. I was searching for a way to combine a couple .json reports with GitHub Actions CI, and this was the final configuration:

```
istanbul report --dir coverage --include coverage/**/coverage-final.json lcov
```

The good side of this configuration is that all .json files are part of similar directories:

- coverage/grid/coverage-final.json
- coverage/non-grid/coverage-final.json
  etc.

Specifying `lcov` is outputing a lcov report

[image]

[Related Pull Request.](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/pull/8843/files#diff-e98936aa52a6dd7416e4296e9628456227d834f7245967383fd9ff80fd985dadR43)